# Use an image as a fill for a polygon in GeoServer (like overlay google maps)?

Tags: geoserver, style

Locally, I have a geoserver installed. I need to fill the polygon with a picture that is pre-cropped, along the outline of the polygon.
For example, if you use styles, and fill in one color, this is how it looks.

```
<PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name = "fill"> <ogc: PropertyName> #ddd </ ogc: PropertyName>
          </CssParameter>
        </Fill>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name = "stroke"> <ogc: PropertyName> # ff0 </ ogc: PropertyName> </CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name = "stroke-width"> 0.5 </CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
```

It works, but I need the casting to be done with a picture, scaled, and clearly tied to the boundaries of the polygon. In short, I need the geoserver exactly as done in google maps - an example of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Comment: The example you point to is just another layer over the top of a layer - it has nothing to do with polygons - please add more details of exactly what you are trying to do using the [edit] link

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @IanTurton With all due respect, but are you kidding me? This is an example, ignore it, you did not pay attention to the fact that, firstly, the layer we have is an image, secondly, it clearly follows the coordinates, and repeats, the mountain river and the whole area. just like on the map, in the third the polygon can be square in shape, and that's not the point, with this function in Google maps, I can just do what I need, once again, you see that, as you said, an additional layer glued to the coordinates?

Comment: @IanTurton Well, consider that I need to take a bitmap in exactly the same way, which will contain the photo of the polygon. and attach it to the coordinates of the polygon, if you don’t understand how to do this, it’s not necessary that the question is not complete, seriously, I don’t know how to do it. its even more complete

Comment: @IanTurton 
Why complicate things is simple. I have a png picture, it has coordinates that describe the polygon, in which a snapshot of this polygon. I need to display these pictures on a map (but this will be a Google pass task) in essence I need to form a map of such polygons.

Comment: @IanTurton 
It’s as if all these polygons http://prntscr.com/ryd9j0 did not contain a vector fill, but the images were cropped exactly along the contours, and we would have a satellite image of this entire area consisting of these polygons with bitmap images, seriously if you if you don’t understand what I’m talking about, then you don’t even try to help, it won’t work out for you, I would be happy to describe in more detail, but these are all the details, this is the task. No more details.

Comment: @IanTurton Or we’ll make it easier how can I do the same on the geo server, take the same image from the Google example and the geo-server map, and I need to stick it there directly to the same coordinates as in the example, that's all I need

Comment: I still can not understand what you are trying to do. Please add an example of the image and the polygons you want to use. If you just need to add georeferenced images it is easy, if you need arbitrary polygons it cannot be done

Comment: @IanTurton 
geo-referenced image, only there should be a lot of them, so let's start from this time it's easy